# Storage allocation in a const in g++

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, constants

I understand that c++ compilers do not usually allocate storage for a const int under certain conditions and resort to const folding. I tried out a simple program to test this :

```
int main()
{
    const int num = 5;
    int a[num];
}
```

I compiled using the -g flag and ran it in gdb. When tried to access the address of the variable num here, It showed some valid address. I did not expect this. Any insights here?

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: I'm not a guru in this domain, but I found this about `-g` flag: `On most systems that use stabs format, -g enables use of extra debugging information that only GDB can use`. I see no reason for the compiler to not let you update `num` during runtime while debugging (even if you meant it as a constant; maybe you declared it wrong and wanna change it for current instance)

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not aware of that. I haven't expicitely provided any optimization flags though.

Comment: If you didn't specify any, then optimizations are off by default.  If you compile with them turned on, most likely the constant will be removed unless you odr-use it.  You can turn on optimization using `-O3` for the maximum optimization.

Comment: @uIM7AI9S the code I have shown is the code I compiled as it is (with headers ofc). I see no reason for why the compiler would allocate storage for const here other than the'-g' flag allegedly affecting it

Comment: @NathanOliver -o3 seems to have stripped the gdb debug symbols also, I'm not able to access 'a' and the source code list alongwith 'num'

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that c++ compilers do not usually allocate storage for a const int under certain conditions and resort to const folding.

It's not clear to me whether constant folding "usually" happens, nor that the occurrence of constant folding "usually" causes the compiler to not allocate storage. The compiler will determine, somehow, whether constant folding is appropriate, and whether to allocate storage. Certain things you might do, such as passing a pointer or reference to the `const` object to a function, can affect its decision.

In any case, if you compile with `-g`, then that is definitely something that can steer the compiler toward allocating storage for the `const int` variable. This is the easiest way to ensure that `print num` in GDB actually works.

Comment: I wanted to see the compiler 'not' allocating the storage for that const int...hence the program...since it is quite possible that gdb might store or allow the access of symbols where this const might also have been stored, I tried to access it's address. Is there any other way to see the compiler 'not' allocating the storage for a const...

Comment: @user102958 You're now asking a different question, that I don't fully know the answer to. I would suggest that you post a new question, rather than asking this in the comments section.

Comment: @user102958 "Is there any other way ..." -- sure: turn on optimization, and your entire program will turn into a `return 0` equivalent for your machine.

Comment: @EmployedRussian But I think the OP's question is whether there is a method that they can use to *observe* the absence of an allocation for the `const` object. I am not sure about the best way to do that.

Comment: Isn't that what optimization achieves? They can observe lack of allocation (as well as lack of everything else). Without optimization, most compilers _will_ allocate storage for everything, `const` or not.

Comment: I don't think using `-g` has any impact on if the compiler chooses to allocate storage for any variable.